# My on hold question needs improvement

Tags: discussion, on-topic, reopen-closed

Asking about my On-hold question,
[What online tools to DIY-anonymize user names (no PII concern)](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/125784/what-online-tools-to-diy-anonymize-user-names-no-pii-concern)

I freely admit my question is naive in comparison to the included linked post. However, when I wrote the post I believed it was relevant to Stats.SE by the example set in the in-post link (upvote 13). I also searched for relevant tags for pre-analysis data conditioning or data-cleaning for which there are 28 posts.

Also the Cross Validated [on-topic](https://stats.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) page includes:

"collecting data"

And from what I was taught, cleaning data, preparing it for processing, is inextricable from the actual processing. Where decisions are made to manipulate the pre-analysis data one way or the other, this impacts analysis.

Please, if you will, instruct me. I just don't understand why this question would be off-topic. As I continue to work in some areas of overlap in statistics, I expect to have more question in the future. I would very much appreciate any guidance or explanation which makes the policies of CrossValidate/Stats.SE clearer for me so that I may contribute more constructively to the community in the future.

Comment: Did you notice that the reason for closure was *not* that the question might need improvement, but only that it is not within the concerns that are considered to be on topic on this site?

Comment: I didn't realize this stats group had such a narrow focus, but looking through the tags, data-cleaning, a related topic, has only 28 posts! My question is not a technical question for Stackoverflow. The question is about conditioning the data _before analysis_, at the point of collecting data from various sources, but before analysis. Is this topic better asked in another forum?